# invert the image color

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

i have a image which i am importing in vue template and the image is in black color. i want the image to be in this color (#0768fd)
how to get this.

i tried assign class and styling but it didnt work

```
<img alt="icon"
:src="require(`@/assets/images/group-icon.png`)                   "
class="icon-class invert"/>
```

```
.icon-class {
  width: 24px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  margin: 0 6px 0 0;
  padding: 2px;
  color:#0768fd;
  background-color:#0768fd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black !important;
}
.invert {
  filter: invert(0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the color of a PNG image with css, use inline SVGs for icons instead so you can change the color on hover for example. That being said, you could (in theory) use the css `filter` property to achieve the result of changing the PNG to a specific hex value, but it is rather hard to achieve the correct color. I created a filter for you that makes your png the color `#0768fd`:

```css
.blue-filter {
    filter: invert(26%) sepia(95%) saturate(2692%) hue-rotate(211deg) brightness(98%) contrast(102%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/32/32441.png"  width="50" />
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/32/32441.png"  width="50" class="blue-filter" />
```

Comment: thank you so much i liked the indetail explanation

Answer (score 0):

Generate CSS filter (close enough) to target HEX code : https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

```css
img {
  height: 68px;
  filter: invert(26%) sepia(100%) saturate(1711%) hue-rotate(207deg) brightness(99%) contrast(111%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/32/32441.png" alt="" />
```